# Excel Addins Using Python Win32com.client

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, python-3.x

For work i need to iterate through an excel workbook using one of the Plugins that was installed on my computer. The Plugin is called PI, which catalogs meter readings.

The first time I start up Excel it works great and win32com.client has no issues. After that the Plugin disappears and I have to restart my computer. I did some research and found out that win32com.client doesn't load plugins. Some people have found a work around using the following code.

```
xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True
xl.RegisterXLL(xll)
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(xlsx)
wb.Close()
```

Using this code I get an integer error. So I tried modifying it to the following:

```
xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.RegisterXLL(xll)
workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlsx)
workbook.Close()
```

The above code allows for the script to run but I still have to restart me computer after it runs.

Does anyone have any suggestions?